# How to Send Serial Communication Data from Android Device to Linux Machine via USB Cable?

Tags: android, linux, operating-system, usb, serial-communication

I'm looking for guidance on establishing serial communication between an Android device and a Linux machine via a USB cable. Specifically, I want to send data from a web app running on an Android tablet to my Linux machine. The scenario involves capturing button presses on the tablet and receiving them on the Linux machine.

Could someone provide insights or resources on how to achieve this? Any advice on the necessary steps, libraries, or protocols to implement this communication would be greatly appreciated.

I tried with UsbManager to connect with Linux operating system didn't work well.

Comment: Android can connect to USB devices and in such a scenario it acts as USB master (USB OTG mode). In a connection to a PC Android is usually the USB client, thus you are bound to the default USB modes Android provides: MTP for file access and optionally if enabled ADB. I would go for an ADB based solution. Use ADB port forwarding and connect an app via TCP to a server on the PC.